# Documentation for the following in Bash shell: !keyword

Tags: command-line, bash

If you do the following in Bash--maybe in other shells as well--you execute a command from your history that matches the provided keyword:

```
$ !keyword
```

I am looking for documentation for this command. I've tried searching through *man bash* page but no luck. I also tried Google but it's almost impossible (right?) to search for punctuation in Google.

I want to know:

1. What order does this command search your history? Oldest command to most recent? Or other way around?
2. I am aware of adding the *:p* option at the end of the command to prevent execution but is there other options? Although not sure what other options I'd want but just curious.

Of course I could figure this out by trial and error but I rather look trough the documentation before I use this neat command.

Perhaps I am looking in the wrong place? Any help in tracking down the documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction). Most history expansion commands refer to the most recent matching command line (the exceptions are references to a command line by number).

The most useful forms are `!prefix` expanding to the most recent command beginning with *`prefix`*, `!?substring?` expanding to the most recent command containing *`substring`*, and `^from^to` which replaces *`from`* by *`to`* in the previous command.

You can extract only a specific word instead of the whole line by adding a [word designator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Designators), as in

```
ls foo bar *~ *.pdf
rm !*
```

[Modifiers](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Modifiers) can performs string substitutions and extract parts of words. The modifier `:p` causes the resulting command to be printed but not executed.

Answer (score 0):

The order is most recent to oldest.

`!n` executes the command with the number `n` in `history`.

`!-n` executes the nth last command in the `history`.

`!!` executes the last command (i.e. `!-1`).

You can also e.g. `sudo !!` if you forgot to prefix something with `sudo`.

You can google for `bang` or `bang bang` to find something on these commands, such as [this](http://www.deadman.org/bash.php) or [this](http://mail.linux.ie/pipermail/ilug/2006-May/087799.html)

Also:

> Most modern shells support csh's bang commands - bash, tcsh and zsh
>   all do.  While some bang commands don't work in all those shells, all
>   of the following do

So you might be better off looking in the `csh` documentation.